# Make a grouped list from Realm requestResults

Tags: swift, swiftui, realm

After query and sorting from Realm by:

```
    // fetch all Items sorted by Type
    let results = realm.objects(Paper.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "Type", ascending: false)
    
    var paperCollatedByType: [String : [Paper]] {
        Dictionary(grouping: results, by: { $0.type })
    }
    
    // pulls out the keys from the dictionary made above, sorted
    var uniqueType: [String] {
        paperCollatedByDate.map({ $0.key }).sorted()
    }
```

Here is my source for making list looks like this:

```
["kyasutoYellowSeparator": [Paper {
    type = kyasutoYellowSeparator;
    width = 111;
    rollLength = 600;
    quantity = 1;
    importDate = 2020-06-28 12:11:19 +0000;
    totalLength = 600;
    isSlitted = 1;
}, Paper {
    type = kyasutoYellowSeparator;
    width = 12;
    rollLength = 600;
    quantity = 1;
    importDate = 2020-06-28 03:18:22 +0000;
    totalLength = 600;
    isSlitted = 0;
}]]
```

And I am figuring to create a list which grouped by type "kyasutoYellowSeparator" :

```
List {
         ForEach(paperCollatedByDate, id: \.self) { (section: [Paper]) in
                Section(header: Text(section[0].type)) {
                      ForEach(section, id: \.self) { paper in
                          Text(paper.type)
                      }
               }
          }//end of list
```

But its totally failed, Please helping me with list making. Thanks for spending time reading my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is fixed variant (tested on replicated simplified model with Xcode 11.4)

```
List {
    ForEach(paperCollatedByDate.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { section in
        Section(header: Text(self.paperCollatedByDate[section]!.first?.type ?? "")) {
            ForEach(self.paperCollatedByDate[section]!, id: \.self) { paper in
                Text(paper.type)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And how about grouping by importDate sir?

Comment: One question - one answer, you know :) ... and btw - I assume you can find many posts on grouping, just search.